# Typescript and jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, angular, typescript

I have the following function:

Updated: added return to $.ajax

```
searchAjax({url = 'app/php/check.php', data}: {url: any, data: any}): any 
{   
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'text', 
        data: { data },
        success: function (return_data)
        {   
            return String(return_data);
        },  
        error: function (xhr, status, error) 
        {   
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            console.log(err.Message);
            return err.Message;
        }   
    }); 
}
```

For now, check.php returns `echo 'hi'`. Just for testing, I'm trying to console.log the response (in this case `return_data`). However I get the error `EXCEPTION: hi is not defined` when I try to console.log it.

Update:
Now I get an object with a bunch of stuff and responseText which contains the actual response.

Comment: You've tagged this Angular2 any reason why you don't use the @angular/http for such requests.

Comment: @JJB May be he has some legacy code that needs to rewrite to Angular2?

Comment: @RomanC
That's why I ask because if it's just that request and he's using jQuery just for that, then in reality he should be using @angular/http.

Comment: @JJB Good point, maybe I should try out http

Comment: @JJB Angular allows to use any javascript library, including jQuery, which was very popular before, and can't solve the problem with the code above.

Comment: @RomanC
Of course it does but there are best practices, I was just asking a general question because this question is tagged angular2 but the code is not using any angular functionality. Now I'm unsure why you have a problem with me asking a simple question. I was not asking you but the person asking the question who has happily replied "Good point" I'm not trying to answer the problem in that question.

Comment: @JJB I think the problem was that I wasn't returning anything at that point. But now that I've got some form of non-error reply I'll try to work through this first and then I'll get to http. Check my update

Comment: @A.Lau
Yes, I see that it was returning hi and not 'hi' so was acting as if hi should be a variable. If you need any help with converting jquery ajax to the @angular/http, edit your question or create a new question and ill be happy to help.

Comment: @JJB I have a vague idea but I'll write a new question so I can have a proper answer. Take a look when you can. Also do you know how to get the responseText from the ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your eval isn't getting the text you think it's getting. I believe your result:   "echo 'hi'"   is stripping the apostrophe so you're actually evaluating  "echo hi". This can be an ajax client issue. Or your API is stripping it. Check to see what your browser is receiving from the API.

Also, echo isn't in native javascript

Comment: `echo "hi"` is php, so what's getting returns is just `hi`. I think I may have worked it out a little, but I think I might try http suggested by others.

Comment: Then you actually are evaluating "hi" which is not defined. What you probably wanted to do is eval console.log("hi"), basically the text printed by the API response in quotes, if you wanted to see the results in console.

Comment: It was mainly because I did not do a proper return. Now I updated it with a return, it returns me an object with the response text, but I can't seem to extract it. I know that you can do it in the `success` function of the ajax, but I'll probably look at angular's `http` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Answering a bit too late.
You are not printing the response. You are trying to evaluate the response as a javascript expression. During evaluation, javascript doesn't see 'echo hi' as a valid javascript string and generates the error 'hi is not defined'. And then you are not printing the ajax response itself. You are printing the evaluation result which obviously is a failure in evaluation. You can print the response by writing:
    console.log(xhr.response);