# How do I send Angular 2 http.post requests to codeigniter?

Tags: angular, codeigniter

Angular Code:

```
sendData(obj){ 
    const userObj = JSON.stringify(obj);  console.log(userObj);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content Type","application/json");
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/ngGet_Controller/posted', userObj, headers);
}
```

CoeIgniter(Controller) code:

```
public function posted(){
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    var_dump(json_decode($postdata));
    print_r($this->input->post());
}
```

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154319/how-to-post-json-object-with-http-post-angular-2-php-server-side/41155043#41155043

Comment: I tried the answer but m not getting what's wrong in my code, i m still getting null on codeIgniter side, should i need to configure something in my codeIgniter? Since The angular response is just fine.

Comment: will you please post "userObj" also.

Comment: my userObj gives me this :- ({"username1":"test","email1":"test@test.com"})

Comment: Somebody PLEASE help!

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line :

```
headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
```

It should be `"Content-Type"` not `"Content Type"`.

Comment: let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); but didn't helped :(

Comment: Use $_POST inside posted function and try again

Comment: tried using (var_dump($_POST);)  but still getting empty array.